# To invite a girl for a drink for example is Sofek kidushin?

Tags: shidduchim-dating

Is it allowed to buy and give some drink or food for the girl during the dating process?

Comment: Is there any intent that this food should serve as Kiddushin? Are there any witnesses?

Comment: Is the man saying as he gives her the food and drink, *harei at mekudeshes li*?

Comment: @sabbahillel One can certainly get married without saying that, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78535/8775.

Comment: @mevaqesh yes but is it a situation in which he makes it ckear to her and the aidim that he is giving it for the sake of kiddushin? The way the question is asked does not make that clear.

Comment: usually when you order food the waiter/waitress hands it to your date and not you

Comment: The possibility for such things renders your first comment basically irrelevant. It is the latter which is. @sab

Comment: @Laser123 Hmm... So maybe the waiter married the girl. Probably a good reason to end the date.

Comment: @lowian no b/c an exchange of money for food isn't kidushin but a business transaction. similarly an exchange of rings under the chuppah is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, it's permissible. Just don't say it's for the sake of *kiddushin.* I think we could reasonably agree on a *devarim shebelev kol adam* level that the average fellow paying for his date's dinner does not intend that they be married right now!

What you're probably thinking of (or if some rabbi said it, his source most likely) is the Shulchan Aruch advising against getting in the habit of single guys sending a single girls *Mishloach Manos*, "as that could lead to *safek kiddushin.* The commentaries there struggle with how that could come about; Rabbi Hershel Schachter acknowledges it's unlikely from a halachic perspective ... "but that's the chumra." Personally (though I'm not sure if this is really the Shulchan Aruch's language) I think it makes a lot of sense on Purim -- it's a day when people are often tipsy, uninhibited, feel that all sorts of things are allowed that normally wouldn't be, so if a lot of single guys are sending single women Mishloach Manos, it's likely sooner or later that one of them will declare *harei at*, and perhaps even in front of witnesses -- maybe just in jest ... but still ...

Comment: How do you know R. Schachter said this? Where does the ShA say this? What is "devarim shebelev kol adam", and how do you know it applies here? Sources?

Comment: @mevaqesh if someone knows enough to use the term "sofek kiddushin", I assume a reasonably high background. A.) YUTorah mp3, I think it's "inyanei Purim." B.) In Hilchos Megillah, talking about Mishloach Manos. C.) Things that [almost] all people take for granted without saying.

Comment: There have been cases of teenagers joking around and a boy has a "mock wedding" giving a girl a cracker jack box ring and saying it. Caused all sorts of trouble and they almost had to write a get which would have made her pasul to marry a kohen.